# How to get number of Frames(or Samples) per sec or ms in a audio (.wav or .mp3) file?

Tags: audio, sample-rate, frame-rate

**some of the terms are but technical but please bare with me**

I've been observing an audio file under an `Python language module`

the audio has a framerate/samplerate of `44100 per sec or hz` and total frames are `9745238` and the duration of the audio is `220 secs` by the file properties whereas it should be `220.9804535147392 secs` and has `2` channels.

after reading a file it returned me a `9745238 X 2` matrix of `16bit signed int` as expected

*where 1 column is channel 1 data and 2 column is the channel 2 data for respective 9745238 frames*

so my question is there any robust method find these values (with 1, 2 channel consecutively i.e. each row or the matrix) per second or millisecond, because when i multiplied the `frame rate (44100)` with the `duration(220 secs)` of my audio file it must return me total number of frames/samples but No, it returned me `9702000` whereas there are `9745238` in total. So how can i get the exact values(rows) per second?

any guesses?

**Edit 1**

I've referred to a good discussion [here](https://superuser.com/questions/388382/what-does-the-sample-rate-and-sample-size-of-audio-means)

and i guess all i need is **bitrate** which is `bitrate = sampleRate * bitDepth`
but how can i get **bit depth** is it `sample size / sample width` or something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **bit depth** in your case is **16**. It refers to how large each sample is, so if you have a 16 bit value for each sample, that **is** your bit depth.

**Bit rate** is a measure of data per second (as I think you know) and hence for uncompressed PCM audio it is **sample rate (44100) * bit depth (16) * channels (2)**

I hope this is all the information you're looking for. You already know the exact file duration in samples. (Every measure in terms of seconds/milliseconds will usually have a rounding error, and so when you're doing computations on audio it's definitely useful to know the duration in samples.) It seems you know every pertinent stat.

PS. For the record, frame and sample are not equivalent. In audio programming, you might come across the term **frame** to denote a number of contiguous samples that are processed in one go: it's also known as a **block** or **vector**. Processing a bunch of samples together reduces certain overheads. You'll see this in the settings of some audio software, where you can change the **block size**.

Comment: thanks for the answer, so when i printed `1st` frame data by using a different `python module` to check the bits, it returned me **`\x00\x00\x00\x00`** as you said 16 bits (8 bits for each channel), which by converting into 16-integer value gave me a vector `[0 0]` as expected, but then in what terms **`a samples`** and **`a frame`** are not equal, is one sample equivalent to the row in the matrix **(vector or a block as you said eg. `[0 0]` for the first sample)** but isn't one frame is the same too? and what are overheads?

Comment: thanks i figured it out, and i mentioned your answer on [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47865690/how-to-get-number-of-framesor-samples-per-sec-or-ms-in-a-audio-wav-or-mp3) for references for other people.

Comment: I'm not sure what those hex values mean but glad to hear you've got it figured out. Bear in mind that it's unlikely the samples are 8-bit as that is extremely low quality (think vintage console games, 8-bit music, etc.) As for frames, perhaps terminology differs. On reflection, it could be that in this context you can use frame to refer to a row in the matrix, ie. samples for all channels at a point in time. But for instance when writing a plugin in C++...

Comment: ...you will pull a frame of audio from the host (the environment in which the plugin is running), which will be an array of N samples for each channel, where N is the block size. You will process that chunk of audio, and push your modified frame of audio back to the host. I don't know in-depth about what overheads are involved, other than that other lower-priority threads will only be run in between two frames being processed.

Comment: could it because the file was initially `.mp3` and i later converted it into `.wav` file, however i played the .wav file it sounded me same like the mp3 one, maybe the latter is the cause, and by meaning block do you mean number of frames right?

Comment: So, I read this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13039846/what-do-the-bytes-in-a-wav-file-represent/13041339) and answer of a user named **hatpaw2** made me think that, we are discussing about the 1 frame (first 4 bytes of the data) only which is under 44 bytes, and it said that the OS additionally adds some RIFF headers when converting (which are like 44 bytes from the starting), however, i did it on windows, do you think it could be the cause?

Comment: Now I'm pretty well in over my head. These are probably questions more for Stack Overflow. Good luck!